# Create a matrix of element (lines) points connectivity python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a matrix.
In matlab, I got to do the following:

```
clc;
nelments= 3   
npoint= 5
connect=(1:npoint) + (npoint-1)*(0:nelments-1).
```

However, in python I do not know how to create such matrix.
I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np 
nelments=3
npoint=5
connect=list(range(1,npoint+1))+(npoint-1)*(list(range(0,nelments))
```

Comment: What is the output of your code in matlab (for those of us who don't have a license to use it and check)? It is hard to tell what you want python to do.

Comment: @ElijahCox
Thank you for your prompt reply. 

The output should be the following:
[1 2 3 4 5;
 5 6 7 8 9;
 9 10 11 12 13]

Size of the matrix is: 3 rows, and 5 columns 

Thank you so much!!

Comment: np.arange(1, 6)?

Comment: @DaniMesejo
Thanks for your comment, 
as I understood from np.arrange is generating spaced values within a given interval.

However, I wanna generate a matrix for example:
I have 3 lines, each line has 5 points so the matrix should be:

[1,2,3,4,5;
5,6,7,8,9;
9,10,11,12,13]

Output matrix should be 3*5

Comment: Is there a name for this type of matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that very closely matches MATLAB's syntax, and takes advantage of numpy's broadcasting and vectorization features:

```py
def make_fancy_matrix(rows, cols):
    return np.arange(1, cols + 1) + (cols - 1)*np.arange(rows)[:, None]
```

Usage:

```py
>>> make_fancy_matrix(3, 5)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]])

>>> make_fancy_matrix(5, 3)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Here's a simple timing benchmark versus the other answer using a list comprehension:

```py
In [2]: np.array_equal(make_fancy_matrix(10000, 50), comprehension(10000, 50))
Out[2]: True

In [3]: %timeit comprehension(10000, 50)
10.9 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit make_fancy_matrix(10000, 50)
746 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see - to do this systematically for m rows and n columns, assuming you start at 1 and want to repeat the last column of each row,

```py
import numpy as np

m=3
n=5
connect = np.array([np.arange(i*(n-1)+1,i*(n-1)+n+1) for i in range(m)])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what exactly I want, .. however, I might need it to be coded, as the numbers and rows, and columns are not fixed, ....
I think I got a way to do, but may I ask about a way to write down a row vector into a column vector ?? transfer row vector to become a column vector ??

Comment: Edited to handle different numbers of rows and columns.